# Rust first step, how to create a Option<Box<T>> from &mut self?

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust for a few days and honestly some concepts are really difficult to understand and apply. I started to rewrite a small part of a component in order to compare the legendary speed of Rust and learn by a concrete project. It's a component to measure time and monitor the program during the execution. It will be a dynamic library used by another program.

My question :

1) How to create an `Option<Box<T>>` from &mut self ? (fn add_son)

```
extern crate winapi;
extern crate user32;
extern crate kernel32;


struct KpiMethod{
    element : String,
    line : u32,
    nb_occ : u32,
    counter_start : i64,
    counter_end : i64,
    total_time: i64,
    kpi_fils : Vec<KpiMethod>,
    kpi_father : Option<Box<KpiMethod>>
}

impl KpiMethod {

    pub fn new(_element: String, _line: u32, _father: Option<Box<KpiMethod>>) -> KpiMethod {
        KpiMethod{
            element : _element,
            line : _line,
            nb_occ : 1,
            counter_start : get_counter(),
            counter_end : 0,
            total_time: 0,
            kpi_fils : Vec::new(),
            kpi_father : _father
        }
    }

    pub fn add_son(&mut self, _element: String, _line: u32) -> KpiMethod{
        //How create a Option<Box<KpiMethod>> of an existing KpiMethod (self) ?
        let mut kpimet = KpiMethod::new(_element, _line, Some(Box::new(self)));
        //Do I need a mutable self to push ?
        self.kpi_fils.push(kpimet);
        kpimet
    }

    pub fn find_son(&mut self, _element: String, _line: u32) -> Option<&KpiMethod> {

        //which is the good and speed method to find a son with key (element,line) ?
        for elem in self.kpi_fils.iter_mut() {
            if elem.element == _element && elem.line == _line {
                //why do I put a return here to fix error ?
                return Some(elem)
            }
        }

        None
    }

}

pub struct KpiAgent{
    kpi_Method : Vec<KpiMethod>,
    current_Method : Option<Box<KpiMethod>>,
    counter_start : i64,
    counter_end : i64,
    date_start : String,
    date_end : String,
    auto_consommation : u64,

}

impl KpiAgent {

    pub fn new() -> KpiAgent {
        KpiAgent{
            kpi_Method: Vec::new(),
            current_Method: None,
            counter_start: 0,
            counter_end: 0,
            date_start: String::from(""),
            date_end: String::from(""),
            auto_consommation: 0
        }
    }

    pub fn method_start(&mut self, element: String, line: u32){

        match self.current_Method {
            None => {
                self.current_Method = Some(Box::new(KpiMethod::new(element, line, None)));
                if self.counter_start == 0 {
                    self.counter_start = get_counter();
                }
            },
            Some(method) => {
                let metfils = method.find_son(element, line);
                match metfils {
                    None => {
                        self.current_Method = Some(Box::new(method.add_son(element, line)));
                    },
                    Some(son) => {
                        son.nb_occ += 1;
                        son.counter_start = get_counter();
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    }

    pub fn method_end(&mut self, element: String, line: u32){
        match self.current_Method{
            Some(met) => {
                met.counter_end = get_counter();
                self.counter_end = met.counter_end;
                met.total_time += met.counter_end - met.counter_start;
                self.current_Method = met.kpi_father; 
            }
        }
    }
}

pub fn get_counter() -> i64 {
    let mut counter: i64 = 0;
    unsafe{
        kernel32::QueryPerformanceCounter(&mut counter);
    }
    counter
}


pub fn main() {

    let mut met = KpiMethod::new("1c".to_string(), 1, None);
    met.add_son("2c".to_string(),2);
    met.add_son("3c".to_string(),3);
    met.add_son("4c".to_string(),4);
    let _toto = met.find_son("3c".to_string(),3);
    match _toto{
        None => println!("Not found"),
        Some(x) => println!("{}",x.element),
    }

    let mut agent = KpiAgent::new();
    agent.method_start("test".to_string(),2);
    agent.method_end("test".to_string(),10);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We like very focused questions, here; having multiple questions in one post is usually not a good idea because it can be ambiguous what the main focus is. Please read [ask], and consider trimming this one down to something more focused, preferably with a [mre]: something like "How can I create an `Option<Box<T>>` from a `T`?"

Comment: The answer to the title question is: `Some(Box::new(value))`, but it looks like you figured that out already -- what don't you understand? (edit: oh, didn't realize it was mistyped once -- was that the main problem?)

Comment: Hi madteam, looks like you accidentally did `Box:new()` insteaed of `Box::new()`. After that, it gets you a lot closer to compiling.

Comment: I see you're trying to create a KpiMethod tree-like structure. Unfortunately, trees, doubly-linked lists and other similar structures are [non-trivial to implement](https://rcoh.me/posts/rust-linked-list-basically-impossible/) in Rust due to [ownership concepts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) which you can read up on. You could use a library implementing a tree structure like [id_tree](https://crates.io/crates/id_tree).

Comment: Thank all of you, I fix some errors and change the post to focus one problem.
Yes I read similar structure isn't easy to implement in Rust. The concept of only one ownership is complicated when you come from Poo world. So I need help from Rust expert ...

Comment: @SameerPuri : Thanks for id_tree, I will try.

Comment: I think that what you want to do is impossible in safe Rust. `Box`es own their contents, but a `&mut self` (mutable reference) does not - the reference is borrowing whatever it points to.

You could come up with some other sort of API that uses e.g. `Rc<T>`, `TypedArena<T>` or similar.